# When does a continuous function map loops to loops?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

> Let $X$ be a space; let $x_o$ be a point of $X$. A path in $X$ that begins and ends at $x_o$ is called a loop based at $x_o$.
>
> Page-327 , Munkres

I have before learned of continuous function presving connectedness and path connectedness, but what more conditions do we need on a function on top of continuity for it to preserve loops?

**[How I understood that path connectedness doesn't imply loop preservation]:** If we have a continuous map $f:X \to Y$, and a path in $X$ $a \to b \to c \to a$ , then we know by continuity preserving path connectedness that:

1. $ a \to b$ gets sent to some path $a' \to b'$
2. $ b \to c$ gets sent to $ b'' \to c'$
3. $ c \to a $ gets sent to $ c'' \to a'' $

The issue is , I don't know if the double primed points are equal to the primed points. So, it doesn't make sense to say that just having continuity preserves loops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A continuous image of a loop is indeed a loop. To see this, first we want to prove that a continuous image of a path is a path:

Let $\gamma: [0,1]\to X$ be a path in $X$, and let $f:X\to Y$ be a continuous map, then $\delta:=f\circ\gamma:[0,1]\to Y$ is continuous, hence a path.

Now we can see that $\delta$ is a loop because $\delta(0)=(f\circ\gamma)(0)=f(\gamma(0))=f(\gamma(1))=(f\circ\gamma)(1)=\delta(1)$

Answer (score 4):

A loop is a continuous function $f: [0,1]\to X$ such that $f(0)=f(1)$,  if we have a continuous map $g: X\to Y$, then $g\circ f$ would be a continuous map with $g(f(0))=g(f(1))$ from $[0,1]$ to $Y$ and hence is a loop.